# Map Slick oneToMany results to tree format

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have written a simple Play! 2 REST with Slick application. I have following domain model:

```
case class Company(id: Option[Long], name: String)

case class Department(id: Option[Long], name: String, companyId: Long)


class Companies(tag: Tag) extends Table[Company](tag, "COMPANY") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("NAME")

    def * = (id.?, name) <> (Company.tupled, Company.unapply)
}

val companies = TableQuery[Companies]

class Departments(tag: Tag) extends Table[Department](tag, "DEPARTMENT") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    def companyId = column[Long]("COMPANY_ID")

    def company = foreignKey("FK_DEPARTMENT_COMPANY", companyId, companies)(_.id)

    def * = (id.?, name, companyId) <> (Department.tupled, Department.unapply)
}

val departments = TableQuery[Departments]
```

and here's my method to query all companies with all related departments:

```
override def findAll: Future[List[(Company, Department)]] = {
    db.run((companies join departments on (_.id === _.companyId)).to[List].result)
}
```

Unfortuneatelly I want to display data in tree JSON format, so I will have to build query that gets all companies with departments and map them somehow to CompanyDTO, something like that:

```
case class CompanyDTO(id: Option[Long], name: String, departments: List[Department])
```

Do you know what is the best solution for this? Should I map List[(Company, Department)] with JSON formatters or should I change my query to use CompanyDTO? If so how can I map results to CompanyDTO?

Answer (score 0):

One-to-Many relationships to my knowledge haven't been known to be fetched in one query in RDBMS. the best you can do while avoiding the n+1 problem is doing it in 2 queries. here's how it'd go in your case:

```scala
for {
  comps <- companies.result
  deps <- comps.map(c => departments.filter(_.companyId === c.id.get))
               .reduceLeft((carry,item) => carry unionAll item).result
  grouped = deps.groupBy(_.companyId)
} yield comps.map{ c => 
  val companyDeps = grouped.getOrElse(c.id.get,Seq()).toList
  CompanyDTO(c.id,c.name,companyDeps)
}
```

there are some fixed parts in this query that you'll come to realize in time. this makes it a good candidate for abstraction, something you can reuse to fetch one-to-many relationships in general in slick.